# How to automatically add logged in user as creator of product

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form that can create a product. My problem is how do I add the logged-in user automatically?

While logged in, when I create a product and look at admin http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin the 'creator' object is blank --- or I have to choose the user manually.

I want to relate a product with a user.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    prodname = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to='images')
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

from .forms import ProductForm, RegisterUserForm
from .models import *

def home_view(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def product_create_view(request):
    form = ProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {
        'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'product/product_create.html', context )

def register_view(request):
    form = RegisterUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterUserForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('product/login.html')
    context = {
        'form': form

    }
    return render(request,'product/register.html', context)
def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home-view')
        else:
            messages.info(request,'Username or password is incorrect')
    return render(request,'product/login.html')

def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('product/login.html')
```

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Product
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import User

class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['prodname', 'description','price','image']



class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:  
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defer saving the object using `.save(commit=False)` and modify it by adding the current user as creator before saving, like this:

```py
def product_create_view(request):
    form = ProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.creator = request.user
            instance.save()
    ...
```

Have a read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) for more information on `save(commit=False)`